# Is there any way to edit Information_schema in mysql

Tags: mysql

I know information schema is read only but I ran into a problem.
I've imported mysql database. Information_schema db also got copied. Its 'views' table has a definer set. I wish to change this as this is causing problems to access some tables.

It gives me access denied to root which has all the permissions and I also tried running mysql with --skip-grant-tables option but with no help.

Is there any way I can change the definer?

Note: its Innodb

Comment: No. You can not "edit" `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` because it is not a real stored data. It is a projection of your current database setup that would contains stuff like meta-info, permissions descriptions and so on. It is generated based on your other data, it's not an independent thing.

Comment: I've an alternative to my original problem where I was not able to access a few tables. I created a new user which was set as definer and missing from my users table. 
But would still like to know if there is any way I can change the definer if information_schema db also got dumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html):

Inside INFORMATION_SCHEMA there are several read-only tables. They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files associated with them, and you cannot set triggers on them. Also, there is no database directory with that name.

Hence they are read only and can't be manipulated.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution to the original problem I faced of not accessing the tables:
1) Create user that was not created.
2) There was actually a view which had a definer set. I dropped the view and recreated with the definer as my own user.

Comment: You could also use the CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW syntax rather than separate DROP and CREATE to achieve the same result.